# Divide column into 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where I'm storing Allowances and Deductions. If the BaseCode is 1 then it is an allowance and if BaseCode is 2 then it is deduction.
I am trying to get the column transformed into 2 columns.

Allowance    Deduction
Something    Something

```
SELECT (
        SELECT INN.FullName AS Benefit
        FROM [AppCNF].[tbl_AllowanceOrBenefitType] INN
        WHERE INN.BASECODE = 1
            AND INN.ID = OUTR.ID
        )
    , FullName AS Deductions
FROM [AppCNF].[tbl_AllowanceOrBenefitType] OUTR
WHERE BASECODE = 2
```

This is what I have tried so far but it is giving NULL for Allowances.

Comment: Some DDL, sample data and expected output would help you to explain what the issue is, it would also make it easier for the people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are after, but most likely you can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,CASE WHEN BASECODE = 1 THEN FullName END AS Benefit
    ,CASE WHEN BASECODE = 2 THEN FullName END AS Deductions
    -- ,... other columns ...
FROM [AppCNF].[tbl_AllowanceOrBenefitType]
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` to condition a result from a column.

```
SELECT 
    IsAllowance = CASE WHEN OUTR.BASECODE = 1 THEN 'Yes' END,
    IsDeduction = CASE WHEN OUTR.BASECODE = 2 THEN 'Yes' END,
    OUTR.*
FROM 
    [AppCNF].[tbl_AllowanceOrBenefitType] OUTR
```